# Is there a way to limit max scrolling speed of Google Chrome on Android?

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome, web, scroll

My web app written in React has an infinite scrolling component, when testing 2000 elements I discovered a visual bug which makes animations look choppy/laggy on Android devices.

This happens when you try to scroll to the end fast.

I tested using Google Chrome browser on Android and iOS, trying to reach the end of list as fast as possible:

- On iOS the max scrolling speed is much lower and it takes **44 seconds** to reach the end of the list, but all of the animations look very smooth.
- On Android it takes **17 seconds** to reach the end but the animation looks terrible.

If I could somehow limit max scrolling speed of my web app OR just 1 specific scroller inside a `div` then that will solve my issue.

Is this there a way to achieve this?